# Как получить из таблицы только те значения, в которых за последний 2 часа цена выросла в Х раз или на Y.?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица postgresql с данными

```
-id
-name
-datetime
-count
-price
```

Хочу вывести только те значения, в которых за последний 2 часа цена(или количество) выросла в Х раз или на Y.
пока что только так делаю

```
select * from table where datetime >now()-INTERVAL '2 hours'
```

Как такое сделать?

Пример

```
1  Tovar1   29.10.2017 11:12:13   3    10
2  Tovar2   29.10.2017 11:10:12   0    15
3  Tovar1   29.10.2017 12:00:00   100  10
```

то-есть количество товара1 стало 100, а было менее чем 2 часа 3. Нужно вывести в ответе Товар1 (ну если ещё во-сколько раз выросло количество-тоже было бы хорошо)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как лежат данные в таблице. Пример бы нескольких строк, и те, которые надо выбрать. А то не понятно, по сравнению с чем выросла цена

Comment: @lDrakonl  изменил

Comment: Вы в вопросе пишите о цене, а в примере говорите про количество. Я запутался

Comment: @lDrakonl  мне и то и то надо. Напишите что-то одно, я по принципу и другое напишу

Comment: `select t1.name, t1.price-t2.price
from   table t1 
inner  join table t2 
on     t1.name = t2.name 
and    t1.datetime > t2.datetime 
where  t1.datetime >now()-INTERVAL '2 hours' 
and    t2.datetime >now()-INTERVAL '2 hours' 
and    (t1.price - t2.price) > Y` схематично примерно так

Comment: @lDrakonl  пишет, что нельзя отнять текст от текста -  t1.price-t2.price

Comment: Приведите текст к числу. To_number или что-то подобное должно быть